# removing an object from a fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, core-data

Is it possible to remove an object from a fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects?

For example I have the following code:

```
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pack.packName IN %@", allowedPackNames];
            for (int i = 0; i < [tempFetchResults.fetchedObjects count]; i++){
                Author *author = [tempFetchResults.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:i];
                NSSet *filteredQuotes = [author.quotes filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate];
                if ([filteredQuotes count] > 0){
                  author.quotes = filteredQuotes;
                } else {
                  //remove this author from the fetchedObjects array 
                }
            }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is the intent to delete the object or just remove it from the results?

Comment: @Svena I just want to remove it from the results

Answer (score 3):

To remove the object from the data store:

```
[self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:object]; 
[self.managedObjectContext save:nil]; 
[self.fetchedResultsController self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest]; 
[tableView reloadData];
```

To just remove the object from the fetched results controller array, you need to change the predicate. Make sure you disable cache (or change the cache name) for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could define a property 'excluded' or something like that of integer type and incorporate that property into your fetch request predicate. Now when you mark a quote as excluded, fetched results controller will do all the heavy lifting for you without refetching and all.

Update #1

Addressing the bigger issue here I think using subquery in your fetched results controller predicate is much better idea.

Try using:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(quotes, $x, $x.pack.packName IN %@).@count > 0", allowedPackNames];
```

as a predicate for your fetch request for fetched results controller and forget about manual filtering.

Basically what this subquery should do for you is filter out all authors that have quotes count fitting your packName criteria. I admit I did not test this query. If you say this won't work for you I will go through the trouble and test it myself.

Comment: Could you first explain a bit in more detail what you are trying to do. Your question was very straight forward, but I want to understand the whole problem you are solving.

Comment: trying to get all Authors with Quotes, where each Quote object has a Pack with packName in the allowedPackName array.

Comment: Updated my answer to fit your problem.

Comment: this did not work 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : ($x.packName IN {"success, happiness, free, business, dreamslove, change"})'

Comment: Thought it would be something trivial that I was missing. Well, i'm glad it worked out!

Comment: Is a SUBQUERY really necessary here? I think the simpler "ANY quotes.pack.packName IN %@" should work, compare my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15829628/1187415 to your other question.